# Project one layer in QGIS using projection CRS of another layer

Tags: qgis, coordinate-system

I am using QGIS 1.6 and have imported a set of latitude, longitude points from a CSV file as a layer. I also have another layer from a shapefile. When I go to `layer->properties` for the second layer I see that the "Layer Spatial Reference System" is

```
+proj=lcc 
+lat_1=42.68333333333333 
+lat_2=41.71666666666667 
+lat_0=41 
+lon_0=-71.5 
+x_0=200000 
+y_0=750000 
+ellps=GRS80 
+datum=NAD83 
+units=m 
+no_defs
```

I would like to reproject the first layer using the second layer's CRS. How can I do this?

When I enable on the fly projection it reprojects the second layer into latitude/longitudes. What I want is the opposite: I want the lat/longs to be projected using the CRS of the second layer. I know that I can choose a CRS when I am saving the first layer but I do not know what CRS I should select.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you go to `Layer -> Set layer CRS` on the second layer, you see either a epsg: code or a custom code written after the projection string.

So go to the first layer, `Save As ...` , change CRS to `Selected CRS`, `Browse` and enter the code in the `Filter` field to get the right projection. And select a different file name than before.

I assume EPSG:2805 is the CRS you want.

Comment: Or rather EPSG:26986 see http://cicero.azavea.com/docs/epsg_codes.html. However, I guess that the difference is little.